# How to generate a random integer in R

Tags: r, distributions, sample, random-generation

I am trying to generate a random integer that follows this distribution.

$$ P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$$
for
$$  k=1,2,...$$

I tried to use sample with some numbers, but i do not know how to use the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the probability mass function of the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

If you use R: To sample from the geometric distribution, first specify the probability $p$ and then use the `rgeom` function:

```r
# The geometric distribution has one parameter, a probability between 0 and 1.
p <- 0.3
# How many numbers do you want to generate?
n <- 10
# Draw random sample from the geometric distribution.
rgeom(n, p)
#>  [1] 7 0 6 8 0 1 0 0 2 2
```

Comment: `ceiling(log(runif(n),1-p))` works too, in effect using the inverse of the complementary CDF on uniformly distributed random numbers